# "free(): double free detected in tcache 2" in dynamic array class in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, free, dynamic-arrays

I want to write a dynamic array class in C++. I get this message: `free(): double free detected in tcache 2` when I run the code.

This is part of my code:

```
        if(num_of_items >= size)
        {
            int new_size = size < 5 ? 2 * size : (int)(3/2 * size);
            int * temp = new int[new_size];
            
            for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
            {
                temp[i] = items[i];
            }

            delete [] items;
            items = temp;
            delete [] temp; // This is the line that the program shows the message

            size = new_size;
        }
```

`num_of_items` is number of full blocks of array. I use a debugger to find the problems place, I find `delete [] temp;` line as problem's line. Why I get this message?

Comment: `temp` probably should replace `items` in the process of resizing, do you really want to delete it?

Comment: The code you've shown has bugs, but not a double free.  Run your code through `valgrind` or build with the address sanitizer enabled.

Comment: Would it not hit a double free when the object goes out of scope? It's also only part of the function, so it's harder to judge.

Comment: @sweenish - Naked pointers don't delete themselves automatically.

Comment: I deleted `temp` after replacing by `items`

Comment: @StephenNewell True. I'm assuming a destructor is in place. That's how I figure OP is hitting a double free.

Comment: The code you show is worrying. But for the given error message the answers below are not correct (though they do point out a real issue). The problem lies in code you have not shown us. This is probably a rule of three violation causing corrupted memory.

Comment: @MartinYork In my idea, these answers are true. I delete the line of code and the problem solved.

Comment: @RezaHosseinzadeh "*I deleted temp after replacing by items*" - that is exactly what you should NOT be doing. You are destroying the memory you just created, leaving your array with a dangling pointer to invalid memory

Comment: @RezaHosseinzadeh No. The error has not gone away your code is still broken you just can't see the issue anymore. A double free means you freed something twice. You have taken away that second free but this means you still have a pointer to a freed object that you are using. This is the worst possible situation the code "appears" to be working but internally is broken.

Comment: @MartinYork So shouldn't I delete `temp`?

Comment: @RezaHosseinzadeh You should show us the class so we can help you find the real problem.

Comment: @RezaHosseinzadeh I wrote a series of articles on how to write a vector class. Have a read: https://lokiastari.com/series/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pointer temp is the new, larger array, which your object needs to hold. You delete it, leaving your object in a bad state.

The remedy is easy, delete this line: `delete [] temp;`

Comment: Where I should delete `temp`?

Comment: You don't. When `temp` goes out of scope, it goes away. Meaning, the variable holding an address goes away. `items`, your class member, has that same address, and you need the data it points to (your array). By `delete`ing `temp`, you are erasing the array, which you don't want to do. Your destructor will be responsible for the final clean-up.

Comment: So code just have deleting `temp` problem? If I delete the line, will it solved?

Comment: It will solve at least one problem, yes. Specifically the one this question is about. You could always just try it and see.

Comment: @RezaHosseinzadeh "*Where I should delete `temp`?*" - not in this code. The new array needs to be destroyed only in the destructor, or a future resize.

Comment: @RemyLebeau When function finished, will `temp` be distroyed? If no, How can I delete it after finishing the function's task?

Comment: @RezaHosseinzadeh the `temp` variable itself will be destroyed, yes, since it is local to the function. But it is acting as a pointer, and the `new`'ed memory it is pointing at will not be destroyed until you call `delete` on that memory.  Which is a task for the destructor to do, or a *later* resize.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you do this in your loop:

```
 delete [] items;
 items = temp;
 delete [] temp;
```

And then repeat. So the second time through the loop, items points to data you already deleted. I think you need to get rid of the second delete[].

Comment: Deleting `temp` is out of loop. After adding `items`'s items in `temp` and replacing `items` with `temp` I delete it (`temp`).

Comment: And now items points to the deleted data. I presume you then use items and maybe later delete it -- or enter this code again, or something. Setting items = temp doesn't copy anything but a pointer.

Comment: Thank you! I did understand